# Wordpress Custom Meta Box Returns Empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I created a custom meta box (author) for a custom post type (books). The box shows up in the admin fine, but I can't figure out how to display the author in my theme.

This is the code used to create the box:

```
/**
 * Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
 */
function prfx_custom_meta() {
    add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Book Author', 'prfx-textdomain' ), 'prfx_meta_callback', 'rabe_books', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );

/**
 * Outputs the content of the meta box
 */
function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
    $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="meta-text" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Text Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
    </p>

    <?php
}



/**
 * Saves the custom meta input
 */
function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );


/**
 * Adds the meta box stylesheet when appropriate
 */
function prfx_admin_styles(){
    global $typenow;
    if( $typenow == 'post' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'prfx_meta_box_styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'meta-box-styles.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'prfx_admin_styles' ); ?>
```

And this is what I placed in my template:

```
<div class="book-author">by:
    <?php $book_author = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-text', true );
    if (!empty($book_author))  {
        echo $book_author;
    } elseif (empty($book_author)) {
        echo "Why doesnt it work?";
    } ?>
</div>
```

Instead of displaying the author, it displays the text "Why doesnt it work?" which I guess means that the value is empty. But it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't even have an input box above...how is that working?

Comment: Try using wordpress advanced custom fields: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Whoops, I don't know how the input got deleted. I think I am going to try out the plugin instead. Thanks for the tip @Masoud.

Answer (score 0):

As mevius mentioned, you're issue is here:

```
<?php _e( 'Example Text Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e

You'll need to assign the box to a data point.

This is a snippet from one of our functions.php file that has this:

```
function css_metadata_box($object, $box) { ?>
<p>
    <label for="custom-css-data">Add custom CSS for this page</label>
    <textarea name="custom-css-data" id="custom-css-data" cols="60" rows="25" tabindex="30" style="width: 97%;"><?php
        echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'custom-css', true ), 1 );
    ?></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="css_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php }

add_meta_box('css-data-box', 'Page CSS', 'css_metadata_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
```